# Java- Having trouble figuring out why there's an arrayOutOfBoundsException going on in my cache simulation

Tags: java, exception, caching, simulation

This method is supposed to:

1. Poke through a text file filled with 32 rows of 10 hex strings.
2. Break them apart using a whitespace in between each as delimiter.
3. Store the hex strings in an array with 10 indices.
4. Since I'm simulating memory I then load the array into a simulated Register class.

I've gotten it to this step, but I'm having trouble seeing why this arrayOutOfBounds exception is occurring for the arrayString[] array.

```
public void setRegister(Register[] r) throws FileNotFoundException{ //pokes through the 
                                                                    //file and extracts hexes

    Scanner s = new Scanner("/Users/adpitt/Documents/document.txt"); //macOS path
    Register reggie = new Register(); //holding reg

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = s.nextLine(); //slam a line into the string

         for(int i = 0; i <= mainMemSize-1; i++){ //iterate through array of registers

             for(int j = 0; j <= this.length-1; j++){

                 String arrayString[] = str.split("\\s+");//smash them to     
                                                          //pieces, space = delimiter

                 reggie.reg[j] = arrayString[j];//THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS. 
                                                //I believe it's in arrayString[j], 
                                                //not sure why.

              }//complete reggie!
             r[i] = reggie;//load reggie into the register array to complete mm
          }
     }
    s.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you splitting the `str` in the inner loop? The `str` value is not changing anywhere inside those for loops. Can you try moving it out of the for loops, and just after `String str=s.nextLine();`

Also what is `this.length`? what if `this.length-1` is greater than 10 (assuming str.split returns 10 hex strings, as per your initial description)?